# Accessing FTP on an external network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ssh, ftp, putty

I've recently set up my first apache server so I do appologise if this question is very stupid.

I am hosting my server from home so I'm having it go through a redictory server (cloudflare) to preserve private details. I have created an ftp link for personal access to transfer and store files on the server but I'm not able to connect to it through FileZilla or Putty.

Is there a way for me to connect to the ftp server on an external network (eg coffee shop wifi) and transfer files?

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to do this.  The easiest way is to forget FTP and use putty and scp or sftp for files.  (scp, sftp and putty all use the SSH transport mechanism, which is both much easier and much safer then FTP).

In order to get SSH and the above working you need to do 3 things -

- Install, activate, configure and allow connections through the firewall for the     appropriate SSH service on your server, if this has not been done already.
- Configure your router to forward traffic from the external interface to your SSH server.
- Find a mechanism to find your connection - this can either be getting it a static IP or using Dynamic DNS or some equivalent mechanism.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the solution however I have done all of this and it still seems to Timeout during the connection. The only thing I'm not sure of is the server is going though a CloudFlare space where I've allowed my other computers to connect to the server however the actual website platform (1and1.com) doesn't have the option to edit the firewall (its a DNS provider). I've tried connecting to the server through Putty and FileZilla.

Comment: Dont run ssh/putty through cloudflare. Cloudflare is a web proxying solution and ssh and FTP are different protocols to http(s).  Also, I am now confused about your setup!  I dont understand, for example where firewalling DNS comes in or why this is relevant to finding your home IP. Maybe you should edit your post to provide detailed information about what you have actually done so wr can point out where it went off the rails)